# Multiple SQL left join return same counted value if there is same date in two tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, left-join, where-clause

I have the following tables:

**calenders** (use for reporting)

Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `calendars` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Sample

```sql
INSERT INTO `calendars`(`date`)
VALUES
 ('2020-05-20'),
 ('2020-05-21'),
 ('2020-05-22'),
 ('2020-05-23');
```

**individuals**

[image: individuals_table]

Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `individuals` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `accepted_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=705 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Sample

```sql
INSERT INTO `individuals`(`name`, `accepted_at`)
VALUES
 ('Zen', '2020-05-20'),
 ('John', '2020-05-21'),
 ('Jane', '2020-05-21'),
 ('Mary', '2020-05-21'),
 ('Ben', '2020-05-22');
```

**organizations**

[image: organizations_table]

Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `organizations` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `accepted_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=705 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Sample

```sql
INSERT INTO `organizations`(`name`, `accepted_at`)
VALUES
 ('Ethan', '2020-05-21');
```

I'm trying to count the rows with the given date in two tables (individuals and organizations) but if there is same date in the tables, it is only return highest counted value.

The query I've been using:

```
SELECT 
    `calendars`.`date` as 'date',
    COUNT(`individuals`.`accepted_at`) as 'individuals',
    COUNT(`organizations`.`accepted_at`) as 'organizations'
FROM `calendars`
LEFT JOIN `individuals`
ON DATE(`calendars`.`date`) = DATE(`individuals`.`accepted_at`)
LEFT JOIN `organizations`
ON DATE(`calendars`.`date`) = DATE(`organizations`.`accepted_at`)
WHERE DATE(`calendars`.`date`) BETWEEN "2020-05-20" AND "2020-05-30"
GROUP BY `date`;
```

**Results**

[image: results]

Comment: That's not the result from the published sample data And please publish sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images which we cannot;

Comment: @P.Salmon just added table schema and sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joins are cumulative so given

```
drop table if exists t1;
drop table if exists t;

create table t(accepted_at date);
create table t1(accepted_at date);

insert into t values ('2020-05-20'),('2020-05-20'),('2020-05-21');
insert into t1 values ('2020-05-21'),('2020-05-21'),('2020-05-21');

SELECT 
    `calendars`.`dte` as 'date',`individuals`.`accepted_at`,`organizations`.`accepted_at`
FROM dates `calendars`
LEFT JOIN t `individuals`
ON DATE(`calendars`.`dte`) = DATE(`individuals`.`accepted_at`)
LEFT JOIN t1 `organizations`
ON DATE(`calendars`.`dte`) = DATE(`organizations`.`accepted_at`)
WHERE DATE(`calendars`.`dte`) BETWEEN "2020-05-20" AND "2020-05-21";
```

returns

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| date       | accepted_at | accepted_at |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-05-21 | 2020-05-21  | 2020-05-21  |
| 2020-05-21 | 2020-05-21  | 2020-05-21  |
| 2020-05-21 | 2020-05-21  | 2020-05-21  |
| 2020-05-20 | 2020-05-20  | NULL        |
| 2020-05-20 | 2020-05-20  | NULL        |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

You could union the 2 tables and conditionally aggregate

```
SELECT 
    `dte` as 'date',
    sum(case when srce = 'i'  then 1 else 0 end) as 'individuals',
    sum(case when srce = 'o'  then 1 else 0 end) as 'organizations'
from dates
left join
(
select 'i' as srce,accepted_at dt from t where accepted_at  between '2020-05-20' and '2020-05-21'
union all
select 'o' as srce,accepted_at from t1 where accepted_at  between '2020-05-20' and '2020-05-21'
) as s on s.dt = dates.dte
where dte between '2020-05-20' and '2020-05-21'
GROUP BY `dte` ;

+------------+-------------+---------------+
| date       | individuals | organizations |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| 2020-05-20 |           2 |             0 |
| 2020-05-21 |           1 |             3 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.003 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. It took me one hour to understand your queries and also I'm not familiar with alias word. That's why. ^_^